# How can I make a list to store each line in tkinter python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tkinter, pycharm

I used a for loop to create many lines to draw a grid on code, and  I want my lines to get clicked on and return a different color. My current code goes like this:

```
for i in range(100, w-100, 100):
         for n in range(100, 700, 100):
             a1 = mainCanvas.create_line(i, n, i + 100, n, tag='grid_line', width=4, activefill=player1Color,                    fill="black")
     for j in range(100, h-100, 100):
         for n in range(100, 700, 100):
             a2 = mainCanvas.create_line(n, j, n, j+100, tag='grid_line', width=4, activefill="red", fill="black")
```

I have created the lines, all i need now is individual coordinates to store them, and I cant figure out how to call them one by one as a variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: standard rule: if you use `for`-loop then keep results on list.